# Mongo service with specific port exposed in a bridge network docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a sample app which consists of three parts:

- mongo database
- node api (server side)
- angular web app (client side)

the goal is to containerize those three parts and run the app.
so to reach there I've created `docker-compose.yml` file like below:

```
# docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build
# docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
# docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down

    version: '3'

    services:

      mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb-instance-microservices    
        ports: 
          - "27020:27017"
        networks:
          - microservices-network

      client:
        container_name: client-instance-microservices
        image: client-microservices
        build:
          context: ./client
          dockerfile: prod.dockerfile
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
          - "443:443"
        depends_on:
           - api
        networks:
          - microservices-network

      api:
        container_name: api-instance-microservices
        image: api-microservices
        build:
          context: ./server
          dockerfile: server.dockerfile
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
           - mongodb
        networks:
          - microservices-network

    networks:
      microservices-network:
        driver: bridge
```

in the server side i am running the main `app.js` which is trying to connect to the mongodb using this connection string:

> mongodb://mongodb-instance-microservices:27020/TestDatabase

the problem is the server can not connect to the mongo db container.
i tried to expose the default port for mongo like below:

```
  mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb-instance-microservices    
        ports: 
          - "27017:27017"
        networks:
          - microservices-network
```

and update the connection string in the app.js file like this:

> mongodb://mongodb-instance-microservices:27017/TestDatabase

and it's work fine.

the question is how to expose different port for mongo container and make it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect between services using a Docker-internal network, you always connect to the *internal* port of the service.  You don't explicitly need to publish ports (in Compose, with a `ports:` directive); if you do, the port you'd connect to is the one on the *right*.

Style-wise, also note that you don't need to manually declare a private network with default options that will only be used within this Docker Compose file (Compose will do something very similar to that for you), and you don't need to declare `container_name:` just for inter-container connectivity (Compose will add a network alias that matches the name of the service).